# How do I get a Wireless N 150 PCI Adapter DWA-525 working?

Tags: wireless, drivers

Can any one help me to install Wireless N 150 PCI Adapter
DWA-525 driver and configuration process  on Ubuntu 12.04 please......

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please start troubleshooting here: [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802)